# Condition in synchronized clause

Tags: java, thread-safety

I would like to use this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25045231/3740179

but I have one question:

condition ? lockobject : new Object() <--- is this section thread safety?

In other words, when one thread reach synchronized clause, can I be sure that the condition is fully execute by only one thread? When I put the condition in individual line I am sure that is not safety but I do not know the behaviour in synchronized clause.

Comment: From the single line you posted, that doesn't look very thread safe. You might want to learn about [locks and conditions](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-5-monitors-locks-and-conditions.html).

Comment: I would like to extend on @M.leRutte s comment: to enter the `synchronized`, the execution has to acquire the lock of the specified `object`. The read to `condition` is atomic, but not thread-safe since two threads could evaluate this to `false`, create separate lock objects and enter the `synchronized`, thus violating the mutual exclusion.

Comment: How can I use this section "condition ? lockobject : new Object() "  as atomic?

Comment: Don't go the road of the SO post you linked to. Just use `synchronized` on the entire method. Trying to outsmart the language and its compiler leads to fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if the condition is evaluated in the synchronized block? No, of course not, that doesn't make logical sense. You can't synchronize until you know what object you are going to synchronize on.